# How to locate element using css selector in selenium webdriver java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am trying to locate the text of the third div role:

```
<div class="jss295">
    <div class="section-header">
        <h3 class="section-header-title">LABELS</h3></div>
    <div role="button" class="jss300 jss299" tabindex="-1"><span class="jss313">system-all</span></div>
    <div role="button" class="jss300 jss299" tabindex="-1"><span class="jss313">paloaltonetworks_iPoiycgPut</span></div>
    <div role="button" class="jss300 jss299" tabindex="-1"><span class="jss313">system-paloaltonetworks</span></div>
</div>
```

I tried `xpath` as follows: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), '" + str + "')]")).getText()`, where `str` is the text I need.
`xpath` works but I'd like to use `cssSelector` instead.

Comment: If you mean that you want to select node by text, then I'm afraid it's not possible with CSS-selector (`:contains` pseudo-class is not supported by Selenium)

Comment: If you have the text in order to select the element then why are you wanting to return the text in the element? Seems to me like you already have it...

Comment: @JeffC - You right, but I want to get the text in order to use it in my tests I want to verify that this text exist after I am performing a n action which causing this text to appear, I want to be able to make sure that while my test is running and creating this text (which is a label) exist and I want to compare my expected result with the actual result.

Answer (score 0):

:contains() CSS pseudo-class selector is removed from the CSS3 spec.If you are using the latest browsers, this will not work which confronts to new CSS standards.

If the className is unique you can use cssSelector as:

```
    span.valueOfClass
```

//It seems all classNames are same in your scenario.

I guess it is better to use XPath.

Just give a try:

```
    By.cssSelector(span[text()$=paloaltonetworks])
```